# g++ compiler -O2 cause program weird

Tags: c++, c, g++, compiler-optimization

I have the following source compiled in g++ 4.8.2

```
#include "mpmc.hpp"
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

mpmc_bounded_queue<std::string> mq(2048) ;
volatile int counter1=0 ;
volatile int counter2=0 ;
#define LOOP 1000000

void gexit(int gub)
{
    printf("(%d),(%d)\n",counter1,counter2) ;
    exit( 0 ) ;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, gexit);
    signal(SIGTERM, gexit);

    void    *func1(void *);
    void    *func2(void *);
    pthread_t tid ;
    long int       icnt = 0;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &func1 , (void *) icnt );
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &func1 , (void *) icnt );
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &func1 , (void *) icnt );

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &func2 , (void *) icnt );
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &func2 , (void *) icnt );

    while( 1 )
        sleep( 500 ) ;
}

void    *func2(void * inum)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    int iret = 0 ;
    while(1){
        while( 1 ){
            std::string s ;
            if( mq.dequeue(s) ){
                iret = __sync_add_and_fetch(&counter2,1) ;
                break ;
            }else{
                usleep( 1 ) ;
                continue ;
            }
            //usleep( 10 ) ;
        }//while
    }//while
}
void    *func1(void * inum)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    char ptr[11]={0} ;
    sprintf(ptr,"%08d",0) ;
    string s(ptr) ;

    while(1){
        while( 1 ){
            if( mq.enqueue(s) ){
                __sync_add_and_fetch(&counter1,1) ;
                break ;
            }
            usleep(100) ;
            if( counter1 >= LOOP )
                break ;
            continue ;
        }//while
        if( counter1 >= LOOP )
            break ;
        usleep(1) ;
    } //while
    printf("func1 done \n") ;
}
```

The mpmc.hpp is lock-free-bounded-queue from here :
http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/bounded-mpmc-queue

now , I compile it by :
g++ --std=c++11 -Werror -O2 testprint.cpp -pthread -o testprint.exe

run it will get the following :

```
func1 done
```

only one "func1 done" , then press control-c print : (1000000),(1000000)

If I compile it by :
g++ --std=c++11 -Werror  testprint.cpp -pthread -o testprint.exe

run it will get the following :

```
func1 done 
func1 done 
func1 done
```

all three "func1 done" , then press control-c print : (1000002),(1000002)

I think compiled without -O2 make more sense , also , -O2 would
cost about 45 secs to get first "func1 done" , but without -O2
would cost only 17 secs to finish all "func1 done"

May I know what g++ optimizer do in this case to cause this happened ?

Comment: OT: You are mixing C and C++

Comment: Compile with `-s` to see what different code it's generating with and without `-O2`.

Comment: @Lorehead , -s without -O2 execution file size is  14720 , -s with -O2 execution file size is  10600

Comment: Search for the function name.  `diff` might also help.

Comment: Oh, and you might try wrapping your calls to `printf()` in a mutex. It’s not necessarily thread-safe.

Comment: Why are you using `volatile` for a global counter? http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/ Your writes to `counter1` and `counter2` use atomics, but you do not read them using atomics, so have a data race. Why not use `std::atomic<int>`? The `mpmc.h` header already uses that anyway, so you already depend on `std::atomic`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results, I see three `func1 done` lines, and it takes roughly the same time whether optimised or not. If you're not outputting to the terminal you could try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf("func1 done \n")` and check it's not just that you're waiting for the output to appear, but the thread finished long ago.

Comment: Also use a separate pthread_t for each thread.